# JavaScript syntax error (I think)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my homework for class and I copied this code straight out of the book and it's not working.  The problem is the copyRight() function isn't displaying.  The countDown() function is being display somewhere else and it works perfectly. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function countDown() {
    var today = new Date()
    var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
    dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
    weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
    newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
    dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
    monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate+1)
    yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2013")
    year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

    var bridalExpo = new Date("February 12, 2014")
    var daysToGo = bridalExpo.getTime()-today.getTime()
    var daysToBridalExpo = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24))

    displayCountDown.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:12pt; font-family: helvetica;'>Today is "
        +weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We Have "+daysToBridalExpo+
        " days until the Midwest Bridal Expo.</p>"
}

function copyRight() {
    var lastModDate = document.lastModified
    var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
    displayCopyRight.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:12pt; font-family:helvetica;'>Today is "
        +weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We have "+daysToBridalExpo+
        " days until the Midwest Bridal Expo.</p>"
}
```

The body tag looks like this: (the other two functions work great)

```
<body onload="scrollColor(); countDown(); copyRight()">
```

The call for the copyRight() function looks like this:

```
<div id="displayCopyRight"></div>
```

I've been looking at this for the past half hour and am not seeing it.  This is also the first time I've written javascript too though so I'm probably missing something.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: You don't need to guess if there's a syntax error: open the error console and see for yourself.

Comment: What error do you get in your console?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ so it's just an assumption on my part that I typed something wrong.

Comment: This seems to be partial code, you should setup a jsfiddle with the whole code

Comment: you're missing many if not any semicolon you can miss, and because you don't even use the comma operator, you defined many global var's.

Comment: @TommyJ Yes, and you can confirm that assumption if you look at the browser's error console. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers if you don't know how to access it.

Comment: @metadings Semicolons are *optional* in JavaScript.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No, they are not optional, they are just *implicit*. Try it if you like to live dangerously, but you'll always have rare cases where you need one and believe me, these rarities are just ugly and hard to debug. Simply use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a syntax error if something isn't being displayed. Syntax errors are when you write something which the parser for the language doesn't understand and It's displayed in your browser (firebug, developer tools, etc).

However, you have 2 functions

```
A
```

And

```
B
```

Variables that are defined in A as local variables cannot be accessed from function B.

Local variables in A cannot be accessible from function B so you shouldn't be able to use

```
daysToBridalExpo
```

in copyRight because the variables don't exist in that scope.

I recommend starting with something more simple. Have you tried hello world to begin with and basic parametric returning? You could make function A return the needed variables to function B.

Comment: Actually, those variables are defined in the global scope; the problem is `daysToBridalExpo` which is local to the first function.

Comment: I don't have much of a choice as to where I start.  This is where my teacher wants me to start so this is where I start.  But your comments have really helped.  I figured out how to fix it! Thanks.